# $_FILES array not returning all selected files

Tags: php

I want to upload multiple files in php. I've on file input box and beside it i've add more button. when user clicks on button new file upload will come. user should be able to upload only five files if five file uploads control will come using add more then alert will come and user can not add another file upload. Now if i am selecting all five files and printing $_FILES array it is showing file name for first and last array index. Code given below:-

```
 Array
(
    [txtProductImage] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 14200127851.jpg
                    [1] => 
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                    [4] => 14200127864.jpg
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => image/jpeg
                    [1] => 
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                    [4] => image/jpeg
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => C:\xampp\tmp\phpBCCE.tmp
                    [1] => 
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                    [4] => C:\xampp\tmp\phpBCDF.tmp
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 4
                    [2] => 4
                    [3] => 4
                    [4] => 0
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 575185
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 0
                    [3] => 0
                    [4] => 660387
                )

        )

)
```

I'd spent lots of time but could not able to get what the issue is. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can we see the html/js code ?

Comment: On button click i am appending new file input and on form submit i've printed the $_FILES array

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us more code? How are you getting files and how are you posting them? Did you checked what errors are for elements of array? You should try to print them from array to see what are the errors. This will give you inside view and where you made mistake. Maybe it's too big picture or not correct type.

Comment: I am using file input as array like this txtProductImage[] for all five inputs and i'd just printed the $_FILES array in action file.

Comment: Got the solution Guys. I was using html everytime instead of appending the new file input. After changing .html to append i got all the uploaded files in $_FILES. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me.

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
ob_start();
var_dump('$_GET',$_GET,'$_POST',$_POST,'$_COOKIE',$_COOKIE,'$_FILES',$_FILES);
echo htmlentities(ob_get_clean()).'</pre>';
?>

<form action="?">
<input type="file" multiple name="files[]" >
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Edit: or if you want max 5, this also works for me:

```
<input type="file" name="files[]" >
<input type="file" name="files[]" >
<input type="file" name="files[]" >
<input type="file" name="files[]" >
<input type="file" name="files[]" >
```

check http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php